# wpf 3D add own class to viewport

Tags: wpf, vb.net, 3d

I would like to make my own shapes and add them to the viewport. I would like to build these shapes in an own class and would like to make it clickable. I cannot inherit from modeluielement3D because it is inheritable. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this

```
public class myclass 
  inherist ...

public geometry
public handlers
and so on


viewport.childeren.add(myclass)
```

I am pretty new to wpf and 3D so would really appreciate a clear explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Let your class inherit from modelvisual3D.
For events I have used hittesting with visualtreehelper.hittest(viewport,mouselocation)
Topic can be closed.